# Error during building cocos 2d x game code?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-x

[image]

See above image. Image containing error i got during building cocos2d x application on device as well as simulator. I downloaded code from this [link](https://github.com/clawoo)

Someone told me i have to install cocos2d x library in my machine, but my doubt here is if we successfully ran cocos2d game application in simulator as well as in device just including cocos2d library in resource folder .. it should be same happen with cocos2d x library???. how i build above project in my device simulator??

Comment: Which XCode and SDK Version are you using? And which version of Cocos2D?

Comment: @Nick Weaver,, xcode 4.2.1 and sdk iOS 5... and i m using cocos2d-x library

Comment: Have you tried Vladimir's suggestion?

Comment: change compiler to "Apple LLVM Compiler" in the target's build settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have old cocos-2d project template that has "gcc 4.2" compiler in settings, while new xcode does not support it anymore.

To fix that go to the project build settings, find "compiler" setting and choose any option that's present there